# Android Edittext looses focus while typing in the keypad

Tags: android

I have one Edittext and there is a listview below of that edittext.Initailly Listview visibility set to GONE. Once user is typing in the edittext then I am making listview to Visible by populating refined results in the listview. But here after typing one letter in edittext, the edittext looses its focus. Again user needs to click on edittext and have to type to proceed. My question is how to make edittext not loosing focus when listview gets its visibity. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just give in xml editext:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textShortMessage" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set

```
edittext.requestFocus();
```

in the place where u are setting the `listView` visible..